# Why does keras model.fit with sample_weight have long initialization time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am using `keras` with a `tensorflow` (version 2.2.0) backend to train a classifier to distinguish between two datasets, A and B, which I have mixed into a pandas DataFrame object `x_train` (with two columns), and with labels in a numpy array `y_train`. I would like to perform sample weighting in order to account for the fact that A has far more samples than B. In addition, A is comprised of two datasets A1 and A2, with A1 much larger than A2; I would like to account for this fact as well using my sample weights. I have the sample weights in a numpy array called `w_train`. There are ~10 million training samples.

Here is example code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=x_train.shape[1], activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train.iloc, y_train, sample_weight=w_train)
```

**When I use the `sample_weight` argument in `model.fit()`, I find that the model fitting initialization (i.e. whatever happens before `keras` starts to display the training progress) takes forever, too long to wait for**. The problem goes away when I limit the dataset to 1000 samples, but as I increase to 100000 or 1000000 samples I notice that there is a significant difference in initialization and fitting time, so I suspect it has something to do with the way the data is being loaded. Nevertheless, it seems weird that merely adding the `sample_weights` argument would cause such a large timing difference.

Other information: I am running on CPU using a Jupyter notebook.

What is the problem here? Is there a way for me to modify the training setup or something else in order to speed up the initialization (or training) time?

Comment: Any insights during the (almost exactly) past year? I'm facing the very same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. The problem is still happening

Comment: I have resolved it myself, wrap the weights in a `pd.Series`. It makes TensorFlow skip some checks.

Comment: This worked! Could you please add this as an answer for future users?

Comment: Ok, I did not already do it because I really really really do hope that this will be fixed soon and crazy workarounds such as these won't be needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is caused by how TensorFlow validates some type of input objects. Such validations, when the data are surely correct, are exclusively a wasted time expenditure (I hope in the future it will be handled better).

In order to force TensorFlow to skip such validation procedures, **you can trivially wrap the weights in a [Pandas Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html)**, such as follows:

```py
model.fit(x_train.iloc, y_train, sample_weight=pd.Series(w_train))
```

Do note that in your code you are using the `metrics` keyword. If you want the accuracy to be actually weighted on the provided weights, to use the `weighted_metrics` argument instead.